# SpriteKit distortion of colored Sprite in level editor

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6.1

I am trying to use the Level editor (sks file) in SpriteKit (xcode6). I don't have a problem setting up the level with the color sprite and making the character move with actions. but when I go to Rotate and lower arm of this character it distorts so bad it is useless. shorting the arm does help but I need and character to be expressive and short arms just don't work. HOW DO I STOP THE DISTORTION ON THE OUTER SHAPE? in this case the body is parent of upper-arm and then to lower-Arm.[image] Any suggest or shared experience would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the lower arm is a child node of a node that has a non-uniform scale transform, rotation will cause distortion. The solution is to not combine rotation and non-uniform scaling — for example, make your upper arm node be a long rectangle to start with instead of using scale to stretch it out.

Comment: the rule: just don't use the scaling tool when rotating! got it!